# Oracle DB view to display columns numeric value to text relative values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

subject of the question might not be relevant of my doubt here.

I am trying to create a view which read value from Db table where in one of the column I have values as 1,2,3 which actually represent 1=request, 2= response and 3= error.

I will be using this view for reporting, so in report I dont want to shows numberic values, inplace of these, I should get request,response or error.

could you please help me how I can create a view to do so..

thanks in advance as I am not much familiar with DB queries.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW blah AS
SELECT CASE WHEN col=1 THEN 'request'
WHEN col=2 THEN 'response'
WHEN col=3 THEN 'error' END FROM table`

Comment: Are you sure there is no table with those descriptions? Hardcoding values and descriptions can be a pain when those values change

Comment: Thanks , I am trying to draft my query as suggested by you but for some reason its not working. I have some other colums also which I need to display along with this column... but those are normal select one..could you please post a query which display multiple columns along with above request query

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the CASE statement.

```
WITH test_data
     AS (SELECT 1 v1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 2 v1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 3 v1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE v1
          WHEN 1 THEN 'request'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'response'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'error'
       END
  FROM test_data
```

So a view would look like:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
 SELECT CASE v1
              WHEN 1 THEN 'request'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'response'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'error'
           END
      FROM test_data;  -- etc.
```

However, I would think that instead of such an approach, you should create a separate lookup/join table to map between the internal value and the user-value. What happens when you need to add a case for code #4, etc?  You don't want to be modifying your query each time.  Think long-term.